# How to find the namespace of a class easily in Python without using an IDE?

Tags: python

Normally, I use IntelliJ for python programming. But sometimes I don't have access to it or just to make a quick edit I open a Python file in a text editor.

At those times, it is really difficult to find the namespace of a class. I am googling it. But it takes time. Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit:**
Looking at the responses, I noticed that my question was not very clear.

I need to find the namespace of a class at coding time, not in runtime. Therefore, introspection methods like using `inspect` or `__module__` doesn't help me.

WildSeal suggests using [online doc](http://www.python.org/doc/). This is good but it is only useful for Python's standard libraries. I want to search all the modules installed in my current Python path. This is easy with IntelliJ. It has already indexed all the files.

I tried to use `grep` to search for the class inside the `site-packages` directory. But it takes a lot of time to search all the files, probably since they have not been indexed.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by *namespace* here? Do you mean the file which holds the class definition? Or it's contents perhaps?

Comment: This is why you should not `import *`.

Comment: what about modifying the namespace?

Answer (score 3):

Let us not forget about `dir()`, which is heavily used by those of us who use vim as our IDE.

Comment: can one set new attributes using `dir`?

Answer (score 2):

Try [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html).getmodule:

```
>>> import inspect
>>> class Foo:
    pass

>>> inspect.getmodule(Foo)
<module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

Lots of other cool stuff in there, too.

Comment: And you can use `dir(inspect)` after the import to find out what you can do with `inspect`!

Answer (score 2):

I use [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) and I've got my `site-packages` as well as other folders indexed in advance.  There are a number of [GUI and command line tools](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/tools.html) that will integrate with ctags to do what you need.  Personally, I use `vim` as a text editor with the TagList plugin ([instructions](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/04/ctags-taglist-vi-vim-editor-as-sourece-code-browser/)).

Answer (score 1):

The special attribute __module__ is the module name in which a class was defined.  It will be '__main__' if defined in the top-level script.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [online documentation](http://www.python.org/doc/), or the documentation installed with Python. If you search for a function or class, you'll get all the relevant information (I assume you meant the package or module of a class or of a function, in the Python standard library).

There aren't so many of them though, at least that people usually use at the same time, so you should quickly get to know them.

Answer (score -2):

You can try :

```
import array
print(array.__dict__)
```